# Create columns in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, html-table, simple-html-dom

I have some values in array like this:

```
$elm = 'a,b,c';
$elm2 = 'd,e,f';
```

I would like to create a table out of this data which would look like this:

```
table:
a d
b e
c f
```

It seems impossible, since HTML tables are created horizontally, I'm always somehow getting this:

```
table:
a b c
d e f
```

I tried many things for instance:

```
echo '<table>';

 foreach($html->find($elm) as $m){
   echo '<tr><td>' . $m . '</td>'; 

 foreach($html->find($elm2) as $m2){
        echo '<td>' . $m2 . '</td>';
    }

echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Which gives me this:

```
table:
a d e f
b d e f
c d e f
```

So the first column is correct but the other ones are spread out horizontally and duplicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some magic:

```
$array = [explode(',',$elm), explode(',',$elm2)];
$array = call_user_func_array('array_map', array_merge([NULL], $array));

foreach ($array as $sub) {
    echo implode(' ', $sub) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
a d
b e
c f
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/142765)

Comment: Thank you but Im getting an error at the lines of both $array in dreamweaver and when I output I get a d b e c f in one line

Comment: @Youss: Your browser might be displaying that in a single line. Change `\n` to `<br />`, so the whole statement becomes **`echo implode(' ', $sub) . "<br />";`**.

Comment: Still a straight line (which is weird I know..) I think it has something to do with my values which are a bit complicated, I just simplified in the question

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
$elm = 'a,b,c';
$elm2 = 'd,e,f';

$explode1 = explode(',', $elm);
$explode2 = explode(',', $elm2);    

echo "<table>";

for($i=0; $i<sizeof($explode1); $i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td>".$explode1[$i]."</td>";
       echo "<td>".$explode2[$i]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>a</td>
       <td>d</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>b</td>
       <td>e</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>c</td>
       <td>f</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**DEMO**

http://3v4l.org/2QCDu

Answer (score 0):

Are we playing golf?

```
foreach(array_combine(explode(',', $elm), explode(',', $elm2)) as $k => $v){
  echo "$k $v\n";
}
```

Comment: (...we are certainly not "explaining answers")